# Encoding `Map ([Text], [Text]) Text` in dhall (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, dhall

What is the best way to encode the Haskell type `Map ([Text], [Text]) Text` in dhall?

**Attempt.** It seems we can't use `toMap` to do this:

```
-- ./config.dhall

toMap { foo = "apple", bar = "banana"} : List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Text }
```

```hs
x <- input auto "./config.dhall" :: IO Map Text Text
```

since we need the domain of the map to be of type `([Text], [Text])`.

Comment: The key is a 2-tuple of lists of `Text`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes.

Comment: I don't know dhall but I know `Map (a,b) c` is isomorphic to `Map a (Map b c)`, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map` in Dhall is just a `List` of `mapKey`/`mapValue` pairs:

```
$ dhall <<< 'https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v16.0.0/Map/Type'
λ(k : Type) → λ(v : Type) → List { mapKey : k, mapValue : v }
```

... and the Haskell implementation encodes a 2-tuple like `(a, b)` as `{ _1 : a, _2 : b }`, so the Dhall type that corresponds to your Haskell type is:

```
List { mapKey : { _1 : List Text, _2 : List Text }, mapValue : Text }
```

You're correct that you can't use `toMap` to build a value of that type since `toMap` only supports `Map`s with `Text`-valued keys.  However, since a `Map` is just a synonym for a specific type of `List` you can write out the `List` directly (just like you would in Haskell if you were using `Data.Map.fromList`), like this:

```
let example
    : List { mapKey : { _1 : List Text, _2 : List Text }, mapValue : Text }
    = [ { mapKey = { _1 = [ "a", "b" ], _2 = [ "c", "d" ] }, mapValue = "e" }
      , { mapKey = { _1 = [ "f" ], _2 = [ "g", "h", "i" ] }, mapValue = "j" }
      ]

in  example
```